# Log Files Location

Tags: logging, windows-ce

We are developing A COM for a WIN CE device. It will be used by ASP pages. It will log execution information to a log file. What is the ideal location for keeping our log files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no "ideal" location.  Keep them where you have space and where you can find them again.  Maybe you have persistent storage and you want to put it there (e.g. `\Hard Disk`, `\USB Disk` or `\Storage Card`), maybe you don't want it persistent and you want to put it in a temp log folder like `\Temp\Logs`.  Basically it's up to you and your device architecture where you want them.  There no way for anyone else to tell you where they should go.